# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'seg'

Tags: nlp, spacy

Tried to follow this line of code from this link https://spacy.io/universe/project/spacy-sentence-segmenter to create a sentence segmenter. Encountered the following error：ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'seg'.

Spacy already installed. Didn't find any information about which module should be used for this 'seg'. Anyone could help? thanks.

```
from seg.newline.segmenter import NewLineSegmenter
import spacy

nlseg = NewLineSegmenter()
nlp = spacy.load('en')
nlp.add_pipe(nlseg.set_sent_starts, name='sentence_segmenter', before='parser')
doc = nlp(my_doc_text)
```

Answer (score 2):

Sentence Segmenter is a third-party module that is different from your spaCy installation. You need to install it separately:

```
pip install spacyss
```

You can find more information in the project's [Github page](https://github.com/tc64/spacyss).

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the module using pip or pip3: 
 pip3 install segmentation